# Error consulta mysql en php error Primary script unknown

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

se me esta presentando este error AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'  cuando realizo una consulta para traer todos los registros de una tabla, lo curioso es que funciona cuando comento la linea que trae el 'nombre'. Lo estoy haciendo en php - mysql, mi código es el siguiente:

```
  $query = "SELECT idequipo, nombre, estatus, idcategoria, idtorneo FROM Equipos WHERE estatus = 1";
  $result = $db->query($query);
  $equipos = array();

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $equipos['idequipo'] = $row['idequipo'];
    $equipos['estatus'] = $row['estatus'];
    $equipos['idcategoria'] = $row['idcategoria'];
    $equipos['idtorneo'] = $row['idtorneo'];
    $equipos['nombre'] = $row['nombre']; // si comento esta parte funciona
    $response[] = $equipos;
  }
```

Tengo consultas a otras tablas de la misma forma y no lanza el error, también verifique el query directo en phpmyadmin y no hubo problema, solo ocurre en php y con esta consulta. No sé si el error es muy simple o algo estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias

Comment: Es el unico error generado?

Comment: Si. Cambie la ruta del archivo pero ahora solo responde "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" en el javascript y en el log no muestra ningún error nuevo.

Comment: Perdón no podría, pero te agradezco.

Comment: vale, no hay problema

Comment: Mira si hay algún nombre de equipo con caracteres especiales. Dependiendo de la codificación a veces eso da problemas después. Si quieres, como ejemplo, restringue la consulta a un `WHERE estatus = 1 AND idequipo IN (1,2,3,4)` por ejemplo (entendiendo que el 1,2,3,4 no tienen caracteres especiales seguro) y dinos si así funciona

Comment: Prueba a poner esto antes de ejecutar `query()`: **`$db->set_charset("utf8");`** Suena mucho a un problema de codificación. Si sigue dando error, verifica que tanto en el HTML como en PHP tienes también `utf8` como juego de caracteres. Y si sigue dando problemas revísalo en la tabla y en los datos en sí mismos.

Answer (score 0):

seguramente algún valor de la columna 'nombre' tenga un carácter especial que funcione como escape de cadena dentro del JSON devuelto. Revisa los valores de los nombres como primera medida. Si encuentras algo que pueda funcionar como escape de cadena, debes modificarlo y validar el formulario de ingreso para que no permita este tipo de caracteres.

Prueba limitar la consulta (solo para una prueba) a algo similar a esto y si no devuelve un error, entonces hemos encontrado el problema.

```
"SELECT idequipo, nombre, estatus, idcategoria, idtorneo FROM Equipos WHERE estatus = 1 and nombre = 'Carlos'";
```

Reemplaza 'Carlos' por algún nombre que exista en la BD.

Espero te sirva.